# Inconsistent behavior with RegExp Object in RegExp.match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have detect a strange behavior in regexps created with the RegExp object:

With this code:

```
var exp1 = /./;
var exp2 = new RegExp('.');
​
var test1 = exp1.test('large\n\ntext..etc.');
var test2 = exp2.test('large\n\ntext..etc.');
​
var match1 = 'large\n\ntext..etc.'.match(exp1);
var match2 = 'large\n\ntext..etc.'.match(exp2);
```

...the result is:

```
test1 = true
test2 = true
​
match1 = 'l' (first match)
match2 = null
```

With the regexp maked with the regexp object from a string it finds nothing...

Why does this happends?

Thanks!!

EDIT: I have tried it in Mozilla Firefox 3.5, I haven't tried in other browsers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me in Firefox 3.5.9.  `test1` and `test2` are both `true`, and `match1` and `match2` are both `['l']`

Comment: I have edited the main message. I tried it in Mozilla Firefox 3.5, I haven't tried in other browsers... 

Thanks for reply.

Comment: Works for me as well: FF 3.6.3